# Get key on url and check key on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, get

```
$id = "1234";
if (isset($_GET['bot_id'])) {
    $_GET['bot_id'];
    if ($_GET['bot_id'] == $id) {
        $_SESSION['bot_id'] = $_GET['bot_id'];
    } else {
        $erro = 'ChatBot not work!';
    }
}
if ($_SESSION['bot_id'] != $id) {

    echo '
    suppor admin website<br />

    <font color="red">' . $thongbao . '</font><br />

    </form>
    ';
    exit;
}
```

Code me get url bot_id 1234
me want get multiple key id 1234  and 4567 and 7896,....
pls help me get multiple on mysql or file text
My problem, I have many customers, and I will provide customers with 1 id can view website, and i want to manage those ids that i can add or delete, by sql or txt file

Comment: Hi! From here these key id should come? Also, why the tag mysql and database? I do not see any database query in your code.

Comment: id = 1234 when me connect domain/index.php?bot_id=1234 work but me want add multiple id key , you can help me check id bot on file text or mysql , me dont know